# Sobre WordPress ¿Qué son los plugins y para qué funcionan?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Quería saber para qué son y para que se usan los pluggins?
Cuando va bien que los utilice para ayudar en la funcionlidad de WordPress?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola! te recomiendo darle lick a las etiquetas de tu propia pregunta, allí te da una breve explicación de que son

Answer (score 1):

Los plugins de wordpress son paquetes de funcionalidades que agregan utilidades a la base de wordpress.

Entre ellos, se encuentran funciones para el administrador, para las paginas y tambien widgets que podes agregar a tu visualización (theme).

No hay una respuesta a cuando va bien que los uses. La ideal seria que usaras la menor cantidad (cada plugin es mas cosas en memoria y mas cosas que hay que ejecutar al mostrar una pagina), pero mas alla de eso, esta en lo que uno necesite y quiera de su WP.

[fuente en wp.com](https://wordpress.com/es/support/plugins/anadir-plugins/)